# Phonegap PushPlugin with a badge number and grouping feature

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have used [pushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to recieve push notification in my phonegap android application. Everything is working correctly. Only issue is when multiple messages are present in the notification bar, the last message overrides the previous message. I would like to group all the messages under the app as whatsApp does.

I tried adding notId parameter and setting it to random number from my server side code. Doing this actually displays multiple notifications but does not group then.

I would also like to know how to add badge number to my app. Basically a number which will tell the user that so many number of notifications are come. As it is in whatsApp (ex. 2 messages received). I have added [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge) plugin to handle that, but I am not sure whether it has to be done in phonegap or will i have to modify java code (plugin) to achieve this.

I know this topic is addressed previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003458/phonegap-pushnotification-node-gcm-group-notifications) but there is no answer to it. hence i have raised a new question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do think (**although I totally am not sure**) that WhatsApp doesn't actually show separate notifications, instead it concatenates the non-read messages on server before sending just one new notification that overwrites the current as you said. For example, if you initially have one message not read causing this notification

```
WhatsApp
Hey dude!
```

and then you receive another message, the notification sent is

```
WhatsApp
2 new messages from 2 contacts
```

or if the sender is the same contact

```
WhatsApp
Hey dude!\n
What is up?
```

You could use the `pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);`if you only needed iOS support but as it doesn't support the Android for that feature you need to use something else and that plugin you mentioned looks good for it. Seems like it is quite easy to use like this (after it is installed)

```
cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(3);
```

Comment: Thanks @sanfor for utilizing your time to answer my question, I would like to have the functionality you mentioned in ur 3rd example. Since my app is going to recive messgae from only 1 server I would like to club those messages as WhatsApp does when we receive message from same sender.

Comment: The Badge plugin is totally fine, but I am not sure how I could use it. As I feel notification part is done in Java(plugin).